# SSR in simple regression analysis with zero intercepts

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I've just started studying regression analysis but I'm stuck right now.

I have a question about SSR in simple regression analysis with zero intercepts.
In text book, it says SSR with zero intercepts is represented like (3.46).
However I couldn't understand why $SSR$  is $\sum(\hat y)^2$ not $\sum(\hat y -\bar y)^2$. Does $\bar y=0$ in simple regression with zero intercepts?

And is it also valid that $SST=SSR+SSE$ in here? And what is $SST$ in this situation?

Thanks for everyone in advance.

[image]

Comment: This might be a better fit for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)...

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Probably one would more quickly find people who know the answer at stats.stackexchange.com, but still the question fits here. I have a quite a few occasions recommended posting at stats.stackexchange.com when the question was too subtle for math.stackexchange.com but not too subtle for stats.stackexchange.com . But I wouldn't say this one is very subtle.

Comment: Do not cross-post across sites in general (it is fine if you found out later that the question is more suitable in some other site, but this isn't the case here). If you are patient enough you will get an answer here.

Comment: @StubbornAtom and MichaelHardy Thank you for your advice. I didn't know cross-posting is not recommended. Please excuse me.